# Wordpress: Scheduling tweets at unique times using cron jobs

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, cron

I'm trying to create a basic application which allows users to schedule multiple tweets to be posted on their timelines at user-specified times. So basically, this will be the flow of the application:

1) Twitter login
[image]

2) Taking permission from user
[image]

3) User gets redirected to a form, where they can add new message fields by clicking on `Schedule a tweet`. They can then fill the content of the tweet, and the corresponding time at which they want the tweet to be posted on their timeline.
[image]

I'm using Abraham's `twitteroauth` to implement Twitter OAuth in my application.

Source code of the template responsible for displaying the form on redirecting the user after a successful login:

```
<pre>
<?php
/*
 *Template Name: Callback 
*/

?>  
<?php

    session_start();
    require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', " http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/callback/");

    $request_token = [];
    $request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    $request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token'])
    {
        echo "Opps! Something went wrong!";
    }

    else
    {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

        //print_r($access_token);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    }

    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

    //$user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

    //$response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => 'fsociety'))





    //$response = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/update'), array(
                                                                        //'status' => 'Conceit to fall on parasol.'


?>


<script>

    var count = 0

    function addNewMessage(count)
        {       
                if(count > 5)
                {
                    window.alert("NO MORE THAN 5!");
                }
                else
                {
                    var celeb = document.createElement("input");
                    celeb.type = "text";
                    celeb.name = "tweet" + count;
                    celeb.placeholder = "Tweet" + " " + count;
                    celebrity.appendChild(celeb);

                    var date = document.createElement("input");
                    date.type = "datetime-local";
                    date.name = "date" + count;
                    date.placeholder = "message-date" + " " + count;
                    celebrity.appendChild(date);

                    celebrity.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    celebrity.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                }
        }        

</script>

<form method = "POST" action = "">

    <fieldset>
        <a style = "color:red" onclick = "addNewMessage(++count)">Schedule a tweet</a>
        <div id = "celebrity"/>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field' ); ?>
        <button type="submit"><?php _e('Add Campaign', 'framework') ?></button>
    </fieldset>


</form>


</pre>
```

Now, as commented in the above source code, I'm able to post tweets to a user's timeline by:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => 'fsociety'))
```

Now, my question is, how can I schedule user-defined tweets at user-defined times using cron jobs inside the same template by extracting the tweet content and time information from the form fields?

PS: I know how to implement a cron job using a plugin. However, since my cron job depends on the form field data, I want to write the code for scheduling this cron job inside my above templates file itself and not inside a custom plugin.

EDIT:
I have created a custom post type which stores the form data inside the `wp-postmeta` table.

Comment: What do you mean by "my cron job depends on the form field data"? The cron job will start a new script and cannot access the form. How have you solved that? Is the data from the form stored in a database?

Comment: @MartenKoetsier What I meant to say was that the cron job of posting tweet at specific times will depend on the tweet content and time set my the user by filling the form. And yes, I have created a custom post type which stores the form data inside the `wp-postmeta` table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would normally create some script that will check which actions should be performed at that time and run that script regularly (once a minute, or once an hour, depends on your needs) using cron. So, there is one fixed cron job that calls the same script. The script handles actions. (if your site receives enough hits, you could also use wp-cron)

Comment: @MartenKoetsier I know how to create a cron job using hooks, but can I define my script inside the same template as my form is defined instead of defining inside a custom plugin?

Comment: it can be in the same plugin, but it should be a different function. It will not be called in any user request, only from the cron request. Perhaps the Example in [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) helps?